# Как мигрировать с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webpack, искусственный-интеллект, webpack5

меня зовут Анатолий, я начинающий айтишник, я учусь на айтишника. Мой первый проект заключается в миграции web-проекта с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5. Помогите пожалуйста мне разобраться как мигрировать с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5.

Я думаю, что это знает GPT-4. Если у кого-то есть возможность задать мой вопрос GPT-4 - буду очень благодарен за ответ искусственного интеллекта, но буду рад и лично вашему ответу.

Столько проектов сделано на Webpack  3, что что новая профессия появилась «Инженер по миграции с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5». Всё больше вакансий требует уметь мигрировать с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5.

Comment: Прочитать документацию по Webpack 5, создать новый webpack-конфиг и постепенно воссоздать в нём всё то, что было в конфиге Webpack 3, по необходимости заменяя пропавшие фичи/плагины на их ближайшие аналоги

Comment: В новой версии фич везде становилось больше. Куда в Webpack пропадают фичи при миграции с Webpack 3 на Webpack 5? Как найти ближайший аналог?

Comment: Вбиваете интересующую вас фичу в гугл и смотрите историю изменений в результатах поиска